# Is it impossible to write 4 bytes for a float and 8 for double at QdataStream ?

Tags: c++, qt

I need (I must) to write a lot of floats to a qdatastream and it is neccesary I use only 4 bytes.
setFloatingPointPrecision or writes 4 or 8 both for floats and doubles.
I thought that it was applicable to qreal, but I surprise it works on float a double type..

Is there any solution ? Thanks

Comment: It is unwise to put any kind of floating point number in a persistent store or network communication.  IEEE float is not the only float out there, alas.

Comment: @zack, hence why he is using Qt's storage/network mechanisms (based upon his comments below). So long as he is declaring which version he's using on each end, the representation will stay the same and no issue storeing the data... http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdatastream.html#versioning

Comment: @g19fanatic The only mention of floating point *format* (as opposed to *size*) in that documentation is in the `<<` operator overloads, and it does not give me confidence that it actually does the right thing when the native floating point format is not IEEE.

Comment: @g19fanatic I just checked the code, and it does *not* do the right thing.  It blindly assumes the native floating point format is IEEE.  See http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/corelib/io/qdatastream.cpp#line824

Comment: @Zack Or it could be that QDataStream works just fine on every platform that Qt supports.  I'd be amazed if this wasn't the case.

Comment: That's not good enough for a serialization format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible workaround is to write a function and overload it:

```
void writeReal(QDataStream& out, float f)
{
    out.setFloatingPointPrecision(QDataStream::SinglePrecision);
    out << f;
}

void writeReal(QDataStream& out, double f)
{
    out.setFloatingPointPrecision(QDataStream::DoublePrecision);
    out << f;
}
```

Now simply use this function for serializing floats and doubles

```
QFile file("file.dat");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QDataStream out(&file); 
writeReal(out, (float) 3.14);  // Casting to float so single precision will be used
writeReal(out, (double) 3.14); // Casting to double so double precision will be used
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, thanks a lot for this kludge. The only thing I would add is reading+restoring the initial value of floatingPointPrecision, to keep the POLA.

Comment: Why not simply set to single and back to double every time you i/o a float, and leave the default for double?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write only four bytes, have you considered `static_cast`ing your `double`s to `float`? I'm not sure what a `qdatastream` but that might work for you.

Comment: I'm using Qdatastream to manage my data i/o operations. Thinking in the future, network communication, platform independent and endianness free. In addition, I dont want to cast a double to float, I simply want to use 4 bytes for float and 8 for double. Qdatastream.setFloatingPrecision aplies 4 or 8 to both....